# Generic date format function in Hibernate HQL

Tags: mysql, spring, postgresql, hibernate, hql

I have a query written in **HQL** for a JpaRepository class which used to look like that and was working as long as we were relying on **MySQL/MariaDB**:

```
@Query("SELECT label, DATE_FORMAT(creationTimestamp, 'dd/mm/yyy'), count(*) "
      + "FROM Event "
      + "WHERE ..."
      + "GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(creationTimestamp, 'dd/mm/yyyy')")
```

However, we now need to also support **PostgreSQL**, in which the `DATE_FORMAT()` function does not exist, and is instead `TO_CHAR()`.

But unfortunately we cannot have both at the same time, and the last thing we want is having to fork our codebase to support both DBMS.

Is there any way to benefit from generic date formatting in HQL without having to directly call underlying functions of the DBMS in use?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this isn't supported out of the box in Hibernate (not sure why as would have thought it was simple to implement).

You can make this work by extending the dialect. This is trivial and will create a generic HQL function that keeps your application database-agnostic.

First, create a class for the dialect that you want to extend such as:

```
class ExtendedPostgreSQL9Dialect extends PostgreSQL9Dialect {
    ExtendedPostgreSQL9Dialect() {
        // Add a generic 'date_format' function that can be used across databases
        registerFunction("date_format", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.DATE, "to_char(?1, ?2)"));
    }
}
```

Then change your datasource to use the custom dialect, for example by changing hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">com.mycompany.dialect.ExtendedPostgreSQL9Dialect</property>
```

You can then use `DATE_FORMAT(MYDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')` in your HQL